# Google Sheets: import cells from different spreadsheets based on date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating an overview spreadsheet that aggregates the work hours of employees from individual sheets.

One such individual work plan spreadsheet looks like this and shows the work hours per employee per ISO work week number:
[image]

The goal is this representation in the overview spreadsheed (empty cells in the overview spreadsheet for the week number prior to project start):[image]

My current solution: add the following formula in row 41 of the work plan spreadsheets: `=OR(E29>today(),ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())=E30)` and then filter for the dates using the following formula to import the relevant data: `=Filter(Importrange(URL,"'PROJECT PLAN'!E33:AH33"),Importrange(URL,"'PROJECT PLAN'!E41:AH41"))`

The problem with the current approach: when a project starts in the future (there would be empty cells for the work weeks prior to project start), the work hours are imported without considering the work week and don't match the week number of the overview:
[image]

My question: is there an efficient way (no importrange and condition in each cell of the overview spreadsheet) to import the data so that it matches the ISO week number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain better when the error occurs? `when a project starts in the future`, do you add a new sheet?

Comment: @Emel I've updated the explanation. I hope it is clearer now. Looking forward to your suggestions

Comment: why can't this be achieved by using a simple SUMIFS formula to only sum hours that match the relevant week number ?

Comment: @MikeMoy it is different spreadsheet. I don't know how to combine importrange and sumifs formulas...

Comment: why do you mean by different spreadsheet, are you talking about the same file or different file

Comment: your explanation/descriptions are lacking

Comment: If the problem is importing information from other sheets within the same file, you can use `A1Notation`, for example:` "Sheet Name"!A1:B2` or `Sheet2!A2:B2`. [Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#expandable-1) more examples.

Comment: @MikeMoy it's a sheet from a different file

Comment: ok simple to do

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem by making the call using A1Notation?

Comment: @Emel Actually I do not see how A1Notation could help me here...I've decided to import the data from all spreadsheets into one tab in the overview sheet and then use ```SUMIF``` to get the relevant cells per week.

Comment: @hunter-gatherers From what I understand, you have not been able to solve the problem in an efficient way, right? One solution would be to use a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) approach. Have you considered it?

Answer (score 0):

create a new tab in your high level tracking spreadsheet

import all all the hours into the new tab from the spreadsheet that contains all the hours

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1235678910abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy-z", "'TAB_NAME'!A1:X5000")
```

> ```
>     modify as appropriate:
>     
>     1235678910abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy-z (from spreadsheet URL that you want to import from)
>     TAB_NAME (tab name from the spreadsheet that you want to import from)
>     A1:X5000 (cell range on spreadsheet that you want to import from)
> ```

now you have all the hours imported into the high level tracking spreadsheet

perform a basic SUMIFS formula to only sum hours that match the relevant week number

done !

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I have several spreadsheets from which to import the data into the overview spreadsheet. Is there a way to produce the solution without the "help tab"?

Comment: the above method can be applied to several spreadsheets

Comment: Yes, but then I need to create a help tab for every additional spreadsheet right? Given that I have several hundred spreadsheets from which to import data this is cumbersome...maybe there is a way to combine sumifs and importrange

Comment: Yes it is possible I am sure, but it would be a terrible method. You would end up creating thousands of individual import requests, this is not ideal for obvious reasons. Also when someone is looking at the arrogated hours for a particular week and they say....those hours do not look correct, where is that figure coming from.... they will not be able to easily see a breakdown how that arrogated figure was arrived at without scouring through the hundreds of different spreadsheets as you put it.